# parseException in pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark code that is written which reads three JSON files and converts the JSON files to DataFrames and the DataFrames are converted to tables on which SQL queries are performed.

```
    import pyspark.sql
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql import *
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    import json
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
    from pyspark.sql.types import *

    spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("project") \
    .getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sqlContext=SQLContext(sc)

reviewFile= sqlContext.read.json("review.json")
usersFile=sqlContext.read.json("user.json")
businessFile=sqlContext.read.json("business.json")
reviewFile.createOrReplaceTempView("review")
usersFile.createOrReplaceTempView("user")
businessFile.createOrReplaceTempView("business")
review_user = spark.sql("select r.review_id,r.user_id,r.business_id,r.stars,r.date,u.name,u.review_count,u.yelping_since from (review r join user u on r.user_id = u.user_id)")
review_user.createOrReplaceTempView("review_user")
review_user_business= spark.sql("select r.review_id,r.user_id,r.business_id,r.stars,r.date,r.name,r.review_count,r.yelping_since,b.address,b.categories,b.city,b.latitude,b.longitude,b.name,b.neighborhood,b.postal_code,b.review_count,b.stars,b.state from review_user r join business b on r.business_id= b.business_id")
review_user_business.createOrReplaceTempView("review_user_business")
#categories= spark.sql("select distinct(categories) from review_user_business")
categories= spark.sql("select distinct(r.categories) from review_user_business r where 'Food' in r.categories")

print categories.show(50)
```

You guys can find the description of the data in the below link.
    https://www.yelp.com/dataset/documentation/json

What I'm trying to do is get the rows which has food as a part of its category.
Can some one help me with it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using expression `A in B` in pyspark `A` should be a column object not a constant value.

What you are looking for is `array_contains`:

```py
categories= spark.sql("select distinct(r.categories) from review_user_business r \
                      where array_contains(r.categories, 'Food')")
```